# Making an array in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am trying to make an array that will have 84x28 values. The array should contain the number 1 repeated 28 times, followed by the number 2 repeated 28 times, and so on up until the number 84 repeated 28 times. I want the output to consist of 1 column and 84x28 rows, each for each number. Is there a way I can get started with this?

Comment: Why do you need an array when you want to output something? Use two nested loops and `echo`/`printf` your values. No need to store them before printing

Comment: Use nested loops that append to the array.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. You're right. Do you know of any resources to point me in the right direction to do what you suggested? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested `for` loops that append to the array.

```
#!/bin/bash

array=()
for i in {1..84}; do
    for j in {1..28}; do
        array+=($i)
    done
done

echo "${array[@]}"
```

Comment: thank you! Would I use echo to see my array? Thank you again!

Comment: Yes: `echo "${array[@]}"`

Comment: Got it. Thanks! When I use echo to see the array, my output is {1..84}. Shouldn't j be inside the loop as well in the 4th line? Than you!

Comment: How are you running the script? That will happen if you run the script with `sh` instead of `bash`, since `{1..84}` is a bash extension.